# How much is a daktil worth in the Aliens For... series?

Tags: aliens-for-series

In the Aliens For... series (Aliens For Breakfast, Aliens For Lunch, Aliens For Dinner), the Ganoobs use Daktils for currency. Insane inflation seems to have taken place: Every time a Daktil is mentioned, it seems a few million is worth two to three earth cents. However, Stephanie Spinner and Jonathan Etra seem to have had some fun with the numbers and I'm not sure if they were consistent with the math.  How much is one Daktil actually worth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mention of the daktil-dollar exchange rate comes in *Aliens for Breakfast*. Aric mentions the Brigade's budget:

> The Interspace Brigade works on a very tight budget. We have 47
> million planets to look after. Our yearly allowance is 249 billion
> daktils. That comes to about sixty-seven cents a planet.

So at this point the exchange rate is **$1 = 7907 daktil**.

"Many months later" during the events of *Aliens for Lunch* it appears that the daktil has risen against the dollar. We first learn that Aric's new form of transport is much more cost effective:

> “Microwave beaming is the latest in budget transport methods,” said
> Aric. “Much cheaper than freeze-drying. We save fifty thousand
> daktils—that’s $18.04 in Earth money—each trip.”

which amounts to an exchange rate of **$1 = 2771 daktil**, so in the course of those months the daktil's value has increased by a factor of 3.

In a later encounter in the same book:

> "We used a new method—holo-faxing. Only ten thousand daktils, or three
> and a half Earth dollars per item."

which is a rate of **$1 = 2857 daktil**. This is broadly similar to the earlier number, and the discrepancy is maybe just a rounding error.

Finally we learn about the cost of the invisibility technique:

> “The Brigade works on a very tight budget, young man,” said Aric
> sternly. “Every ten minutes of vanishing costs half a million
> daktils—that is $183.15 in your money.

This works out to **$1 = 2730 daktil**, which is again broadly similar to the other values.

In the final book *Aliens for Dinner* I did not encounter any mention of daktils.

So it seems that in the events of the first book $1 is worth about 8000 daktil, and in the second the value of the daktil rose to about 3000 per dollar. All the values given in the second book seem roughly consistent with each other. Clearly there are a lot of daktils to the dollar, but it is not as outrageous as "a few million is worth two to three earth cents" - in fact it's not so different to the exchange rate for the Italian lire.